# Find text value in file, print it out?

Tags: shell

I've got a shell script. I want to open a file, and copy out a bit of text from the file. Example:

// foo.java

```
public static int ID_RED = 100;
public static int ID_GREEN = 200;
public static int ID_BLUE = 300;
```

// pseudo-code:

```
int pos = find("public static int ID_RED = ");
echo(file.substring(pos, end of line);

pos = find("public static int ID_GREEN = ");
echo(file.substring(pos, end of line);

pos = find("public static int ID_BLUE = ");
echo(file.substring(pos, end of line);
```

// desired output:

```
100
200
300
```

So I want to open foo.java, and print out the values found at the end of those lines. I think it'd be easier to do this in perl or python, wanted to see if there was a simple way to do this in a shell script, though,

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^public static int ID_/{s/;.*$//;s/.* //p;}' foo.java
```

This doesn't *exactly* match the criteria implied by your pseudo-code, but it does the job for this particular input.  Consider replacing `^public` by `^ *public` if there might be leading whitespace.  Replace `ID_` by `ID_\(RED\|GREEN\|BLUE\)\>` if you don't want to match `ID_YELLOW`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "public static int ID_RED = "   foo.java | cut -d " " -f 6 | tr -d \;
grep "public static int ID_GREEN = " foo.java | cut -d " " -f 6 | tr -d \;
grep "public static int ID_BLUE = "  foo.java | cut -d " " -f 6 | tr -d \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '[ ;]' '/public static int/ {print $(NF-1)}' foo.java
```

or

```
sed -n '/public static int/ {s/^.*= *\([0-9]\+\);/\1/; p}' foo.java
```